# GNOME background window always show up when there are notifications

Tags: gnome, 19.10

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 GNOME 3.34

I had a problem where gnome always change the current app (window) to be minimize when some background app had an alert (browser / chat notification).

To reproduce.

1. Open browser (full screen / maximize)
2. Open other stuff (full screen / maximize) your current app now, the browser loses focus (on your back of current app)
3. Browser send some alert
4. The current window become your browser, and minimize you current app suddenly

How to disable this feature? or how to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu (Gnome Shell) never minimizes by itself. What do you mean by "minimize"? "Minimize" in Ubuntu is the same as "Hide", i.e., the window disappears from the desktop and cannot be seen if you close all open windows.

Comment: Sorry, will re write my question. Its not minimized but it is under the current active window. I can simplify that question.

Comment: you might get lucky trying notificaiton tweaks (backup first)

https://extensions.gnome.org/#